# How Does VBA's InStr React When There Are Two of What You Search For?

Tags: vba, substring

I have a string where I want to get the first two characters following the first period of a string because the prefix before varies so I can't used MID. I was thinking of using InStr, but how does InStr work when there are multiple instances in the string of the character you're searching for? For example the strings I'm searching have a format like this:

xx.xxxx.xx.xxxxx 
xxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx

Does InStr return an array of positions? The position of the first character being searched for? The last?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instr returns the position of the *first* occurrence of the string, after the position indicated in 'start' parameter, whose default value is 1. If you want to search for multiple occurrences , you'll need to set up a loop to call Instr multiple times, each time passing the result of the previous Instr function (plus 1) in the 'start' parameter.